# setSelectedItem in JComboBox by firing event

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox`

```
JComboBox tableChoose = new JComboBox();
tableChoose.addItem("Bill");
tableChoose.addItem("Bob");
tableChoose.setSelectedItem("Bill");
```

and some handling methods

```
public void addComboActionListener(IComboHandler handler){
    tableChoose.addActionListener(handler);
}

public Object getTableChooseSelectedItem(){
    return tableChoose.getSelectedItem();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fileReaderWindow.getTableChooseSelectedItem() , null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

As you see, I set "Bill" as first selected item. When I run the program, I have to reselect "Bill" in order to fire the event in `actionPerfomed`.

Is there a way to fire the event without reselecting the item in JComboBox? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding the listener before setting the selected item?

Comment: Probably [fireActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#fireActionEvent%28%29)

Comment: @gtgaxiola It's `protected`, you can't call it unless you make your class extend `JComboBox` (which is not the OP's scenario).

Comment: [Mark Peters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753004/how-do-i-programatically-send-actionevent-to-jbutton) answer is the best approach of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

Add the action listener ***before*** setting the selected item:

```
JComboBox<String> b = new JComboBox<String>();

b.addItem("A");
b.addItem("B");
b.addItem("C");

b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox<String> src = (JComboBox<String>) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("ActionListener called. '"+src.getSelectedItem()+"' selected.");
    }
});

b.setSelectedItem("A");
```

Output:

```
ActionListener called. 'A' selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `actionPerformed()` method passing a dummy `ActionEvent`. For example:

```
tableChoose.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(tableChoose, 0, ""));
```

the parameter should be ignored and the `fireActionEvent()` method should be triggered.

**Warning** this suggestion was devised looking at the source code for [JComboBox](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.java.html). The comments state to not call this method directly so you would do this at you own risk as the implementation could change in the future.

Further look at the source code didn't show up any other ways to fire the notification besides calling the `setSelectedItem()` method.

Comment: It's a `protected` method, you can use it only if your class is in the same package as the one that contains the method. So the OP won't be able to call it without extending `JComboBox`.

Comment: thanks @BackSlash, I revised the answer changing the suggested method