# How make a button pressed when corresponding key on a keyboard is pressed? JavaFX

Tags: java, events, button, javafx, handler

For example, I created a button labeled "1". Whenever this button is pressed, 1 is appended to a textField. However, I can add 1 to a textField simply by typing 1 on my keyboard. When doing so, I'd like by button to get view as if it was pressed instead if a key. 
I've been thinking thant may be it's possible to manage this issue in this way:

```
   rootNode.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            textField.appendText(event.getCharacter());
            if(event.getCharacter().equals("1")){
                // here button should be pressed
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there some method, that can change  appearance of the button?
Thanks is advance.

@James_D , You program works correctly, but I connt apply your solution to my program. Maybe it's because I customized my buttons. Have a look at a part of my code:

```
    HashMap<String, Button> buttons = new HashMap<>();
    int btnVal = 1;
    for(int j = 5 ; j >= 3; j --){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i ++){
       Button btn = createNumberButton(Integer.toString(btnVal++), inputField, i, j);
       rootNode.getChildren().add(btn);
       buttons.put(Integer.toString(btnVal), btn);
       }
    }
    rootNode.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        Button btn = buttons.get(event.getText());
        if (btn != null) {
            System.out.println(event.getText());
            btn.arm();
            inputField.appendText(event.getText());
        }
    });

    rootNode.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
        Button btn = buttons.get(event.getText());
        if (btn != null) {
            btn.disarm();
        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753004/how-do-i-programatically-send-actionevent-to-jbutton

Comment: @BhavikPatel It's JavaFX and not Swing.

Comment: Calling `button.setPressed(true);` doesn't work?

Comment: If I understood you correct, you want to make keys that enters the equal text into your textfield? Like A, B, C -> text.append(A, B, C), but a button will show the pressing action?

Comment: @James_D , there's no such method in Button.

Comment: @NwDx , no, I want an appearance of a button to be changed whenever corresponding key is typed!

Comment: @Anton [Sure there is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setPressed-boolean-)

Comment: Ah, ok. But than you are on a wrong way. Why you want to add the key typed to your root node and not directly to your button?

Comment: @Anton, Ah, sorry; that is not a visible method...

Answer (score 0):

Use `button.arm()` (and `button.disarm()` to "release" it).

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PressButtonOnTyping extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setDisable(true);

        root.add(textField, 0, 0, 3, 1);

        Map<String, Button> buttons = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 9; i++) {
            Button button = createButton(i, textField);
            buttons.put(Integer.toString(i), button);
            root.add(button, (i-1)%3, 1+ (i-1) / 3);
        }
        Button zeroButton = createButton(0, textField);
        root.add(zeroButton, 1, 4);
        buttons.put("0", zeroButton);

        root.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            Button button = buttons.get(e.getText());
            if (button!=null) {
                button.arm();
                textField.appendText(e.getText());
            }
        });

        root.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            Button button = buttons.get(e.getText());
            if (button!=null) {
                button.disarm();
            }           
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Button createButton(int value, TextField target) {
        String s = Integer.toString(value);
        Button button = new Button(s);
        button.setOnAction(e -> target.appendText(s));
        return button ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```